# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode' while writing into file?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape new content and write it into a file but it is giving 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib2 as urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import codecs
link = 'http://www.hindustantimes.com/delhi-news/delhi-man-shoots-    girlfriend-in-leg-after-argument-blames-snatchers/story-   CzA8JmgafX7tNUroilovoO.html'
reqlink = urllib.Request(link)
page = urllib.urlopen(reqlink)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser') 

fw = codecs.open('hlink7.txt','w')

var = soup.findAll('p')

for i in var:
      fw.write(i.string.encode('utf-8'))
```

how to resolve it?

Comment: Before writing into file, just add a check: `if i.string:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception indicates that you are invoking a method `encode` on an object which is `None`. So you should check the object first, before invoking the method. Modify your code like the following:

```
for i in var:
      if i.string:
            fw.write(i.string.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to encode content of `p` tags then you may have to try with `text` instead `string`.

Like this,

```
for i in var:
      fw.write(i.text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if i is not None:
```

should work also :-)